# BadMethodCallException - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getAuthIdentifierName()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have installed Laravel 5.4 and used the `php artisan make:auth`. Everything was all fine, I set up my database and migrate everything. I also tested the login and registration and it was working perfectly.

After that I managed to set up my other controllers and models. After I tested one of the controller (Basically, I store an image in the database and then display it). And it worked fine I stored the image and then displayed it.

However, since then I receive an error when I try to login or register.

When I try to access http://localhost:8000/login or http://localhost:8000/register I receive the following error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getAuthIdentifierName()

For this one I am not entirely sure which part of my code I should share but this is my Modal User.php:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

use App\User;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */


    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Thank you in advance guys, if you need other parts of my code I will be happy to share.

Comment: share your routes  and controller files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all first run `php artisan migrate` make sure you have a tables in your database

> User.php // user model add a primary key to get rid of this error

```
 protected $primaryKey = 'yourPrimaryKey';
```